# Attendance punch/shift pairing algorithm

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, solver

I developed an attendance system where employees record their punches using a terminal which the system later imports.

When the times are imported I need to pair them with the expected times.

To make it more clear:

Employees have shifts defined for each day of work. Each shift has a start and end time.

So a typical case would be 2 shifts:
8 - 13 and 14 - 18

Now employees comes to work and record punch times using a terminal.
At the end of the day I might have something like:

7:30, 13:15, 14:01, 17:56

I now need to allocate each punch time to a shift and for that shift whether it's paired with the start or the end.

If the punches were exactly 4 then it would be easy but:

- employees sometimes punch more than once (by mistake) and so you have many punches with times close to each other
- employees sometimes forget to punch (so you will have missing punches)
- employees sometimes work late and so you may have an additional actual shift (6 punches instead of 4) but also in this case maybe they forget to punch (you may have 5 punches then instead of 6)

The goal is to allocate the punch times to the correct shift start or shift end taking into consideration all the above.

I was thinking of using the microsoft solver foundation library to solve this but I have never used it and perhaps someone can guide me as to which solver to use and how to model the problem.

OR, if you have other ideas on how to go about it that's ok too.

-- Example scenarios --

```
Shift 1: 9 (A) - 13 (B)
Shift 2: 14 (C) - 18 (D)

Times: 8:45, 13:20, 18:15
Solution: 8:45 --> A, 13:20 --> B, none --> C, 18:15 --> D 

Times: 8:45, 13:30, 18:15 
Solution 1: 8:45 --> A, 13:20 --> B, none --> C, 18:15 --> D
Solution 2: 8:45 --> A, none --> B, 13:20 --> C, 18:15 --> D

Times: 8:45, 13:45, 14:12, missing, 19:00, 21:00
Solution: 8:45 --> A, 13:45 --> B, 14:12 --> C, none --> D
19:00 --> E , and 21:00 --> F (E and F being start and end of an additional 'unexpected' shift)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What if employee doesn't punch the card at the end of the last shift? Do you take days into consideration? e.g. 8:00, 13:00, 14:00....... 8:00. So it looks like someone worked from 14:00 to 8:00 which is not true.

Comment: If an employee has a shift that goes into the next day.. say 20:00 to 02:00 (next day) then, for the day in question, the shift ends at midnight and I automatically add a punch for that. If he doesn't punch at 20:00 then it's a missing punch for the 20:00 to midnight shift. 

if employee doesn't punch at the end of the last shift it should be seen as missing punch. If the end of the last shift is midnight the punch is added automatically so it can't be missing.

In your example then he would have a missing punch for the 2nd shift end.

Comment: In the edge case where the employee has a shift say 20:00 to 23:00 but stays late and works till 02:00 next day... it would appear as if he has a missing punch for 23:00 using current solution... For now such a case is handled manually by a human.

Comment: If you have defined times for when each shift starts and ends (e.g. 8:00,13:00,14:00,20:00 are only possible), then you can sort list of punches for each employee for each day and handle misses for each possible situation, e.g. end of shift is recorded 13:00, but the start is not so you assume it is a miss and add it yourself. You do this for the rest of shifts and you are done. If there is a situation where someone punches 8:00, 20:00 then you know you have to add 13:00 and 14:00.

Comment: it's not that simple though. Some cases are pretty simple but I need to handle all possible scenarios and there are many.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for an algorithm exactly as you do, and couldn't find, so I decided to create my own one, so what I did is as follows:

1. get the `fromdate and`todate`,
2. fetch `punchTimes` of the period (given the above range) - create two list one for punch-in and the other one is for punch-out,
3. create two nested for loops; the first one will iterate over each day between `fromdate` and `todate` so you will have the current date on each iteration. the second loop will iterate over the punch-in list so that you can filter by employeeid, punch-date, and min of timeoftheday; having this particular record, if not null; you will filter out the max from same date...

you can include shift criteria and get more specific records...

Comment: Thanks for answering and sorry for the incredibly late reply.
Can you elaborate a bit? I didn't quite get what your algorithm does.

Comment: Here below I will share a working code snippet that I have used in my Payroll application: